# World of Warcraft: Efficent Archeaology Fragment Farming

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm planning on doing a lot of archaeology farming towards a specific faction.
I used to be very active in Cataclysm, and I am only starting to get back into archaeology with Warlords of Draenor.

I have noticed that my garrison sometimes gives out fragment hunting missions, but those are so infrequent that I cannot rely on those.

I would like to solve either Warlords of Draenor or Pandaria fragments, ideally for the crates. The faction I'd like to target is heavily mixed with other factions that greatly out-number the faction I want.

For example, If I want to gather [Tol'vir](http://www.wowhead.com/currency=401/tolvir-archaeology-fragment) fragments. It would be horribly inefficient to fly all over to do night elf dig sites when you can just solve for a crate and get Tol'vir fragments slower but more reliably.

**Is there a better way to obtain specific fragments besides farming Warlords of Draenor or Pandaria world dig sites?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bran Bronzebeard](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=64922) is selling a [Mantid Artifact Hunter's Kit](http://www.wowhead.com/item=104198) which sets all digsite spawns in Pandaria to Mantis fragments.

You can find him atop the Mogushan Palace where the [Lorekeepers](http://www.wowhead.com/faction=1345) are located.

You need to be exalted with the [Lorekeepers](http://www.wowhead.com/faction=1345) to buy this Item. (Thanks for pointing that out)

With that you can farm Restored Artifacts to buy your Tolvir fragments from him.

Comment: You forget to mention that this item requires lorewalker exalted reputation but otherwise good answer.

Comment: Fortunately Lorewalker rep is the easiest to hit exalted with -- just listen to the Lorewalker's stories if I recall correctly.

Comment: You have to fly around and click on the story scrolls all around pandaria.
Takes about an hour and after that you have to listen to the story.